# Cannot connect to brltty at :0

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, gpu-driver

I just installed updates on 16.04 and got stuck with the login loop issue, but that is now resolved. I'm still not able to get the rest of Unity to work, though. I have a Compaq CQ60 with an NVIDIA GeForce 8200M GPU. I want to use the dual monitor capability, which nouveau doesn't support, so I have the NVIDIA 340.101 driver installed (it's the latest that supports my GPU). I pulled this from the NVIDIA web site. I was able to get ccsm to come up and enable unity, but I still don't get the launcher or the task bar at the top of the display. I have the nouveau driver blacklisted.

Any suggestions for getting the rest of unity to work is appreciated.

The only two lines in .xsession-errors are

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

I don't see any errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Answer (score 3):

1. ALT-F1
2. logon as user
3. sudo bash
4. rm .Xauthority
5. ALT-F7 back on Xwindows, then login again.

Comment: Please explain a little What these commands a re trying to do and what are the results of using these commands.

Comment: And: did not work.